# jQuery datepicker function: datepicker not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to add jQuery datepicker function here. But I am getting an error like 'Datepicker is not a function'. please let me know what went wrong. I went through other questions and tried rectifying but didnot work.

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j("#From").datepicker();
    });
    //$(function () {
    //    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    //    });
    //});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Reports</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Form Starts-->
        <form name="PTTReport" style="padding-top:20px">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div style="padding-bottom:25px" class="panel-heading fixed_panel">
                    <span>Report Filters</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row pb-20px">
                        <label id="From1" class="col-sm-1">From</label>
                        <input type="text" class="col-sm-2" id="From" />
                        <label id="To" class="col-sm-1">To</label>
                        <input type="text" class="col-sm-2" id="To" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-5'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id="From1" class="col-sm-2">From</label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Entire cshtml page,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
          $j("#From").datepicker();
        });
        //$(function () {
        //    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        //    });
        //});
    </script>
     <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Reports</title>
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Form Starts-->
            <form name="PTTReport" style="padding-top:20px">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div style="padding-bottom:25px" class="panel-heading 
    fixed_panel">
                    <span>Report Filters</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row pb-20px">
                        <label id="From1" class="col-sm-1">From</label>
                        <input type="text" class="col-sm-2" id="From" />
                        <label id="To" class="col-sm-1">To</label>
                        <input type="text" class="col-sm-2" id="To" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-5'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id="From1" class="col-sm-2">From</label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you including your JS code in the HTML?

Comment: Just after the <html> tag closure

Comment: It should be *before* the `</head>`, not after it

Comment: Now I am getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Comment: That means that jQuery is not defined when you include the JS. Please edit your question to show the HTML you're using

Comment: done. please check now

Comment: Yeah - as I said before, your `<script>` block needs to go *just before* the `</head>`. You've put it before jquery.js, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `datepicker` JS file in the DOM? Can you update latest code?

Comment: I have added the JS in the HTML page itself right after the <html> closure

Answer (score 0):

> check below snippet. its working

```js
    $(function () {
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    //$(function () {
    //    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    //    });
    //});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Reports</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Form Starts-->
        <form name="PTTReport" style="padding-top:20px">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div style="padding-bottom:25px" class="panel-heading fixed_panel">
                    <span>Report Filters</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row pb-20px">
                        <label id="From1" class="col-sm-1">From</label>
                        <input type="text" class=" datepicker col-sm-2" id="From" />
                        <label id="To" class="col-sm-1">To</label>
                        <input type="text" class="datepicker col-sm-2" id="To" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-5'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id="From1" class="col-sm-2">From</label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem might be with something else in my code then. It is not working at all. Quite weird

Comment: i think you miss path of external 'jqueryui css' , 'jqueryui.js' and may be 'javacriptlibrary'

Comment: It works in a normal html page but not in MVC cshtml page

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(function() {
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  j("#From").datepicker();
});
```